# How to set a DIFF background color of EACH item clicked on my List- can only get it to send 1 color for each item selected using setBackgroundColor()

Tags: java, android

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private String [] myList = new String[]{"Blue", "Green", "Red"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, myList);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

Comment: Please add more context to your issue. Have you looked into creating your own custom Adapter?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use an ArrayAdapter.  Use a custom adapter and set the background of each item.

Better yet-  don't use ListView.  It's been deprecated for most of a decade.  Use a RecyclerView, and set the background color in onBindViewHolder.